# PSPP/SPSS syntax how to

Tags: syntax, spss

How can I use syntax to fill specific rows with specific variables. Lets say I want to fill row 1 to 10 in my "location" variable with the integer 1. Rows 10-70 with 2 and so on. There is no programming I just want to fill specific rows of a variable with specific values instead of doing it manually. I tried using vectors and loops but it only works across columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic syntax would be along the lines of:

```
do if $casenum le 10.
   compute myvar = 1.
else if $casenum le 70.
   compute myvar = 2.
else. 
   compute myvar = 3.
end if.
exe.
```

Answer (score 2):

Presuming your dataset is already populated, [$casenum](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/system-variable/#casenum) addresses rows by their row numbers.

Combine with [IF](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-if-command/) for setting values. You may be able to shorten this a bit by using [RANGE](http://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-range-function/).